# Return name and id property value of all arrays inside object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How to return name and id property value of all arrays? The idea is to make a single map of all these arrays and return the id and name?

Something like this

```
filters.[key].map((option, index) => (
              <ItemFilter key={index}>{option}</ItemFilter>
))
```

I have this array object

```
filters: {
  "services": [
    {
      "id": "1b975589-7111-46a4-b433-d0e3c0d7c08c",
      "name": "Bank"
    },
    {
      "id": "91d4637e-a17f-4b31-8675-c041fe06e2ad",
      "name": "Income"
    }
  ],
  "accountTypes": [
    {
      "id": "1f34205b-2e5a-430e-982c-5673cbdb3a68",
      "name": "Digital Account"
    }
  ],
  "channels": [
    {
      "id": "875f8350-073e-4a20-be20-38482a86892b",
      "name": "Chat"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) or [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to achieve the desired result.

```
Object.values(obj.filters).flatMap(v => v)
```

or

```
Object.values(obj.filters).flat()
```

```js
const obj = {
  filters: {
    services: [
      {
        id: "1b975589-7111-46a4-b433-d0e3c0d7c08c",
        name: "Bank",
      },
      {
        id: "91d4637e-a17f-4b31-8675-c041fe06e2ad",
        name: "Income",
      },
    ],
    accountTypes: [
      {
        id: "1f34205b-2e5a-430e-982c-5673cbdb3a68",
        name: "Digital Account",
      },
    ],
    channels: [
      {
        id: "875f8350-073e-4a20-be20-38482a86892b",
        name: "Chat",
      },
    ],
  },
};

const result = Object.values(obj.filters).flatMap(v => v);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Just `flat` would do the same thing as `flatMap(v => v)`, right?

Answer (score 1):

If `option` is referring to `name` in your example code it could look something like this:

```
Object.values(
  {
    filters: {
      services: [
        {
          id: "1b975589-7111-46a4-b433-d0e3c0d7c08c",
          name: "Bank",
        },
        {
          id: "91d4637e-a17f-4b31-8675-c041fe06e2ad",
          name: "Income",
        },
      ],
      accountTypes: [
        {
          id: "1f34205b-2e5a-430e-982c-5673cbdb3a68",
          name: "Digital Account",
        },
      ],
      channels: [
        {
          id: "875f8350-073e-4a20-be20-38482a86892b",
          name: "Chat",
        },
      ],
    },
  }.filters
)
  .flat()
  .map(({ name, index }) => <ItemFilter key={index}>{name}</ItemFilter>);
```